# "His sight blurs in dizzy."

Tags: grammaticality

> His sight blurs in dizzy.

What wrong with "sight blurs in dizzy"? I don't find any [google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sight%20blurs%20in%20dizzy%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS524US524&oq=%22sight%20blurs%20in%20dizzy%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j0.1036j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for the phrase.  The context is the following: The person is old and sick, and he is walking on the road where is very hot; since he is sick and the weather is so hot, he gets dizzy and his sight blurs before he fall down.

Comment: It means nothing that I can discern. Maybe it wants to say this: "His sight blurs when he gets dizzy". [Vertigo](http://www.webmd.com/brain/vertigo-symptoms-causes-treatment) is one kind of clinically diagnosed dizziness that includes _nystagmus_ as a symptom: "Abnormal or jerking eye movements", but not [blurry vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blurred_vision).

Comment: You should edit this question, and at least tell us what you think it would mean, or could mean. How can we tell you what's "wrong" with it, if we don't know what you're trying to communicate? Add some context to the question and I'll gladly remove my downvote.

Comment: OP's profile doesn't say where s/he hails from, but it's worth noting that many references to [dizzy vision](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22dizzy+vision%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) have **Chinese** associations. Whatever - this question as it stands is Not Constructive.

Comment: Now that I know what you're trying to say, I can think of two rephrasings: _He gets dizzy and his vision blurs,_ or _His sight blurs in dizziness_. You wouldn't say "in dizzy" because _dizzy_ is an adjective, and you need a noun to go with the preposition _in_.

Comment: @J.R. I'd suggest another alternative: *blurs with dizziness*. But I think your answer admirable, and I urge you to post it when, as seems likely, the question is reopened.

Comment: @StoneyBonhiatus Though this might be irrelevant to the topic here, I'd like ask for your kindness answering a question about your comment. Doesn't the sentence *I think your answer admirable* need to be rephrased into *I think your answer is admirable*?

And can I rephrase *as seems likely* into *as it seems likely* in the sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that *dizzy* is an adjective, and we wouldn't conclude a sentence with a prepositional phrase that ends with an adjective. That's why all of these would be wrong:

> Their marriage was always filled with happy.
> After two days in the wilderness, the hunter was plagued by hungry.
> The new piece of jewelry glistened with shiny.

Instead, the correct forms would be:

> Their marriage was always filled with **happiness**.
> After two days in the wilderness, the hunter was plagued by **hunger**.
> The new piece of jewelry glistened with **shininess**.

If the adjectives are desired, we need to remove the prepositions:

> Their marriage was always happy.
> After two days in the wilderness, the hunter was hungry.
> The new piece of jewelry is shiny and it glistens.

So, going back to your sentence, a valid wording might be:

> His sight (or *vision*) blurs with dizziness.

Although I'd probably write it like this instead:

> He gets dizzy and his vision blurs.

Comment: I'd like to ask about the difference between **sight** and **vision** in the sentence *His sight (or vision) blurs with dizziness*.
And shouldn't the *visions* in the sentence on the last line be corrected into *vision*?

I'd greatly appreciate it if you'd answer this. :)

Comment: @SmartH - I fixed the typo. As for the difference between sight and vision, that's tricky to explain. Personally, I prefer _vision_ in my example sentence, but the OP used _sight_ in the question. The word _eyesight_ could also be used. I don't think any of them are wrong, but I think _vision_ sounds most natural. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eyesight+was+blurry%2Csight+was+blurry%2Cvision+was+blurry&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26) would back me up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, which helped understand it along with the related information you added.

This is my guess as to why *vision* might be more natural there and this can be totally wrong as I am not a native English speaker. I think the reason is that *vision* evokes a more concrete image there than *sight* which feels more abstract or generic.